# How to convert percentage to 6 points grading system?

Tags: arithmetic

In my home country grades start from 4.0 and go up to 10.0.

How can I convert percentage of points gotten in a test, to the above grading system?

So for example, what grade would 37.4% be?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your $4$ to $10$ grading system is similar to a "displaced" $0$ to $6$ one.

If the results are given in a percentage you can think $100$ as corresponding to the maximum value of points scored-in your case $6$ and $50$, the presumed base needed to pass a test, corresponds to $3$.

So, let $x$ be the grade according to your system and $y$ the percentage.

Then $x=y*6+4$.

Thus, in your example, $37,4%$ corresponds to $x=37,4*6+4=6,244$.

Comment: Damn this was so easy. I feel dumb now. I'm not good when it comes to maths.

Comment: Would you also be able to help me out on how to start counting the 4.0 from 25% and upwards? As this solution is correct, but if someone has gotten 26% it gets them 5.5, which is not right. Thanks once again!

Comment: @DjAndGo Your concern seems to be that 26% would be 5.56, which rounds to 5.6. But 26% could itself be rounded from a value as small as 25.5%, which would be 5.53, which does round to 5.5.

Comment: @DjAndGo I am also pretty bad at them but still enjoy them :). No need to get discouraged by a(ny) failure. A problem can be deceptively simple to state but extremely difficult to solve. Keep at it!

Comment: @J.G. I am building an online examination platform and I need to convert the points they get in an exam into a grade with the system we use in my country. The problem is that 4.0 should start at 25% and upwards, not at 0%, since you need 25% of the points to pass the exam, you understand what I mean now?

Comment: @DjAndGo Then the formula you need is $0.08x+2$ for $x\in[25,\,100]$. You'll have to handle failures ($x<25$) with separate logic; I don't know what "grade" you want for that.